# Integrate Kibana Dashboard in .Net MVC Application?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, elasticsearch, kibana

Is it possible to integrate Kibana dashboard in my application instead of my application dashboard, that means when you click on dashboard tab it should open Kibana dashboard without login dialogue(direct dashboard).

Answer (score 0):

Sure, but you will have to proxy the connection (that is, some component will have to actually login, retrieve the view and send it to the user).

There has been some discussion about it on the [elastic discussion groups](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/view-a-kibana-dashboard-without-login/164822) and there is a related issue still [open in the project](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/18331) that would allow doing that without login.